# Optimize this PHP Code?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, if-statement, mysqli

I am currently working on a mashup that incorporates many data feeds. In order to display ALL of the feeds that the user wants on one page, I am currently using if statements to cross-check with the MySQL database like this:

```
if($var["type"]=="weather")
```

`$var` being the result of a call to `mysqli_fetch_array`

and then including code relevant to the function (e.g. weather) underneath, and then another "if" statement for another feed, so on so on. The problem is that there will be many feeds, and having all these "if" statements will be slow and redundant.

Is there any way to optimize this PHP code?

Comment: How do you know which `type`s the user wants? If it's `weather, sports, news`, just include that as part of the DB query itself.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution might be to map the "type" to a custom function using associative arrays.

e.g. (pseudo code)

```
function handle_wheater_logic() {
   // ... your code goes here
}

function handle_news_logic() {
  // .. your code goes here
}


$customFunctions = array("wheater" => "handle_wheater_logic", "news" => "handle_news_logic");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_...) {
    call_user_func ($customFunctions[$row["type"]])
}
```

This would eliminate the need to use a lot of if statements. You might as well do the "type to function" mapping in a configuration file or maybe just store the name of the custom function to call for each "type" in a database table - that's up to you.

You can, of course also pass parameters to custom function. Just checkout the documentation for call_user_func[_array].

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$methods = array(
    "weather" => function() {
        // code
    },

    "otheroption" => function() {
    }
);
```

Just use then $var["type"] as a index in the array to get the function:

```
$methods[$var["type"]]();
```

You can obviuosly, for better readbility do something similar:

```
$methods = array(
    "weather" => "wheater_function",

    "otheroption" => "other_function"
);
```

and then call the functions this way:

```
call_user_func($methods[$var["type"]]);
```

To be even more object oriented we can obviously store in the array objects implementing a particular interface, or store object redifining the __call() magic method and use it like  functions.

Comment: Though this works, it's a rather messy solution to a simple problem

Comment: it's the most elegant possible if as i understand there will be a lot of different types; it's the most exstensible solution for sure

Comment: Surely a switch is best though? Doesn't declaring anonymous functions add unnecessary overhead?

Comment: I'm upvoting this because it is technically valid and doesn't deserve a negative, not because it is the best answer here.

Comment: Well... it kind of resembles Strategy pattern indeed, but all the code is still tightly coupled in one `$methods` array. Strategy is more about refactoring bits of code that implement specific algorithms into separate modules of code (usually classes) that can then be instantiated on demand by means of factory/factory method.

Comment: your code is even tightly coupled to the class name; the methods array can be changed even at runtime

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for eliminating a lot of if statements and a huge switch statement just checking for one condition, would be to implement a design pattern such as the Strategy pattern.

This way you will have the code for each type separated, which makes it easier to overview and manage.

Here's an example of an implementation http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/11/22/applying-strategy-pattern-instead-of-using-switch-statements.aspx

Even if you won't implement this strictly it will give you some ideas on how to solve this elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array that associates a function to each feed type:

```
$actions = array("weather" => "getWeather",
                 "news"    => "getNews");
```

Then use [`call_user_func`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) to call the correct one:

```
call_user_func($actions[$var["type"]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphysm for the rescue.

```
inteface FeedInterface {
  public function retrieve($params);
}

class FeedWeather implements FeedInterface {

  public function retrieve($params) {
    //retrieve logic for weather feed
  }

}

class FeedSports implements FeedInterface {

  public function retrieve($params) {
    //retrieve logic for sports feed
  }

}
```

With use of PHP class autoloading, each of above declarations can be in a separate file, possibly namespaced as well. Then your feed retrieval code could look like this:

```
$class = 'Feed'.$var["type"];
$feed = new $class;

$feed->retrieve($params);
```

That's overly simplified and would need some additional code for error handling, discovery of non-existing classes and such, but the idea should be clear.

Comment: and what if we want to change the class? maybe we want to change the class only for unit testing...can we do this?

Comment: I can't see why not. The only requirement for the class is to implement FeedInterface. The instantiating code would require some changes to facilitate unit testing, but like I said the example here is simplified and in real application would require some more piping.

Comment: the problem is the way you reference the class through reflection!

Comment: $class = 'Feed'.$var["type"];

Comment: Ok. In broad meaning of the word it is reflection. Now, why it's bad actually?

Comment: because you're coupling the application to particular class names. It's impossible for example to obtain some sort of inversion of control

Comment: For the third time: the example is simplified. In actual application a factory would be used that would take in `$var['type']`and could return actual production classes, or mocks for tests, or whatever.

Comment: It's hard to avoid them (or similar constructs) though

Comment: Well... you have to create the object somewhere before it's available in IOC container.

Comment: often the container do that for you, you just indicate how to instantiate the classes in some declarative way

Comment: In such case, like it or not, but your container also takes the role of a factory. It just provides a more convenient API and hides such 'ugly' details like use of reflection to create class names. Symfony DI component is a good example of such container

Answer (score 0):

Using either an `If` Statement or a `Switch` statement will be faster than you care about.  It might look ugly and be cumbersome to maintain but it **will** be fast.